# Angular 7+ Reactive Forms: How to find a control if I dont know the path?

Tags: angular, find, controls, angular-reactive-forms

Understanding question: there is still no "deepFind" isn't it ? How can I find a control in a very deep angular reactive form today? (especially then if I do not need to know the path)

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: you don‘t need any code to answer this question, if you know, what it is about,..

Comment: Don't think you can. You can create a recursive to find it but then if there's a duplicate same name exist before your deep nested name then that would be an issue.

Comment: why? in this case I have found two controls with the same name, maybe that was my intention?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I don't know your full use case. But usually when I deal with forms I'd want to get the specific control I want to deal with not multiple.

Comment: the question is very simple: is there built-in possibility to find a control, no matter how deep this control is in the whole form?

Comment: Short answer: No, there isn't any built-in possibility to find a control if you don't have the path for it.

Comment: thank you @SachinGupta, I‘ll make a feature request,..